# Firebase google auth in Swagger (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)

Tags: firebase, asp.net-core, swagger, google-oauth, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Trying to implement firebase google authentication in the swagger

onboard: asp.net core 5, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.3.1,
In fairbase console > authentication > Sign-in method > authentication via google is enabled

On ServiceConfigure method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApi", Version = "v1" });
            c.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();
            
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                {
                    //email and password authentication - works fine
                    Password = new OpenApiOAuthFlow 
                    {
                        TokenUrl = new Uri("/api/v1/auth/password", UriKind.Relative), //here my backend endpoint
                        Extensions = new Dictionary<string, IOpenApiExtension>
                        {
                            { "returnSecureToken", new OpenApiBoolean(true) },
                        },
                    },
                    //try add google auth - troble here
                    Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                    {
                        //Not sure about the endpoints. Its not work with 404 err
                        AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://securetoken.google.com/MY-PROJECT-FIREBASE-NAME"),
                        TokenUrl = new Uri("https://securetoken.google.com/MY-PROJECT-FIREBASE-NAME"),
                        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {                                
                            { "profile", "profile" },

                        }                            
                    }
                }
            });
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
        });
```

class filter:

```
public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var requiredScopes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
            .Select(attr => attr.Policy)
            .Distinct();

        if (requiredScopes.Any())
        {

            var oAuthScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
            };

            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    [ oAuthScheme ] = requiredScopes.ToList()
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

in Configure method:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApi v1");
```

What endpoints for AuthorizationUrl / TokenUrl should call?
Any additinal options for swagger?
I`m new in Firebase. M.b. need aditional adjustments in firebase console?
I would be very appreciate for a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good repo for you. This simple is .NET 5 WebApi project base with the following features implemented:

> Swagger with Firebase login
> Serilog Logging to Amazon CloudWatch
> Encrypted fields in AppSettings
> Soft Delete and Audit Columns
> Multitenancy support
> Data Seeding
> Localization

code sample：[clean-base-api](https://github.com/EdwindTay/clean-base-api/tree/e10046444f443252a0c3b21c9d4b3e6d8f2dd5c4)

Comment: thank a lot for your time, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me - the linked project uses password authorization